# Getting individual outputs from 4 load cells

Tags: arduino-uno

This is my first time using an Arduino, and I want to connect 4 load cells to one Arduino board and then get 4 separate outputs for each load cell on a computer.
What would I need to accomplish this and how would I set it up?
Can all four load cells connect to a single Arduino?

Also, could I get it to work with these load cells in particular:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/HALJIA-Weighing-Resistance-Half-bridge-Original-Silver/dp/B0792WCGJC/

or would I have to use ones with a 4 wire output?

Comment: connect each load cell to a separate analog input .... number of analog inputs depends on the Arduino board that you have, but it is most likely six analog inputs.

Comment: Sparkfun also sells the same load cells, and has a lot of good information regarding their use: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-load-cells

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose there are 'simple' interface boards like the HX711 (google on HX711). A guy named Bogde has written an Arduino library to manage this board which you can find on GitHub (https://github.com/bogde/HX711). There you can also subscribe to the corresponding email group, which is rather lively and also handles similar questions as yours.

Also Sparkfun sells these sort of interface boards and has very good and extensive documentation and tutorials on the site (see comment from VE7JRO below your question).

You can manage 4 load cells with one Arduino depending on the frequency with which you want to read them. If all 4 load cells are used to weigh one platform then Sparkfun sells an interface board to combine them in one "weight sensor" making it even more simple to interface with the Arduino.

Comment: And would I be able to connect four HX711 boards to a single Arduino at once?

Comment: Yes, each HX711 board requires connection with only 2 pins of the Arduino. I advise you to read the information at the site of Sparkfun.